# What is the meaning of the word Sankhara?

Tags: sankhara

In the quote " Sabbe Sankhara Anicca", what is the meaning of word Sankhara?

Is the word "Sankhara" derived from Sanskrit word "Sanskara"?

Comment: Sankhara can be a mental fabrication (e.g., a thought), a cause (condition), a process (conditioning) or an effect (product of conditioning/a conditioned thing). In the phrase "Sabbe Sankhara Anicca", the word sankhara means a conditioned or compounded thing, i.e., anything that is made up of & exists due to causes, conditions, sub-elements, etc. For example, a tree is a conditioned thing (sankhara) because it exists due earth, water, sun, etc, & is made up of various parts & elements (such as leaves, bark, nutriments, atoms, etc). In short, EVERYTHING is a conditioned thing (except Nibbana)

Comment: “Sabbē sankhāra aniccā“ or “all sankhāra are anicca” (cannot be maintained to one’s satisfaction). Sankhāra are our intentions, hopes, and dreams, followed by our speech and actions to fulfill them. “sankhāra” mean all three types (manō sankhāra, vaci sankhāra, kāya sankhāra) that lead to any action, speech, or just thought; however, they all arise in citta (our thoughts). The root cause of that suffering is sankhāra (abhisankhāra). This is why it is said that, “Sabbē sankhāra dukkhā“. Any sankata has a finite lifetime, and is subjected unexpected changes (viparināma) during that existence.